# check if whole group by doesnothave a relationship (Laravel)

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to check if a whole group of elements doesnothave a relationship.

```
$submissions = $user->submission()
        ->groupBy('exercise_id')
        ->doesnotHave('solution')
        ->get();
```

What im trying to achieve is that if at least one submission in the group will have a relationship with solution all submissions with that exercise_id will not show up in the collection.
Right the submissions that have a relationship seperately go into the output collection.
(I'm pretty sure i'm going quite wrong about this but this is the best I came up with - kinda stuck:)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$submissions = $user->submission()
        ->groupBy('exercise_id')
        ->whereDoesntHave('solution')
        ->get();
```